# How to create variable filename and store variable on sd card with Arduino

Tags: arduino, android-sdcard

The example "SD_Test" in the Arduino IDE works perfectly. Now i want to expand it.

**First**: I want to use a variable file name. I found some example in the internet and also in stackoverlow for this, but nothing works (still searching for a minimal example)

```
writeFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "Hello ");
```

i want

```
writeFile(SD, filename, "Hello ");
```

where filename is a variable which handles something like "file.txt"

**Second**: I want to do the same for the content, which i want to save in this file. So instead of

```
writeFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "Hello ");
```

i want

```
writeFile(SD, "/hello.txt", datas);
```

As an example: I can print out this

```
        printf("%04x", datas);
```

Now i want to save this variable 'datas' with 4 hex in the file, exactly how it looks in the serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for writing on the SD card.
You need to download two library files for this names are mentioned in the code.
Remember to format you SD card first into FAT32
Hope this will help you.

```
/*  Author: Ashish Kumar
    Org: INVOOTECH                            */
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;

File myFile;
 char *b="hellow.txt";
 char p;
const int chipSelect = 4;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
 if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect))   //error statement
  {
    Serial.println("initialization failed. Things to check:");
    return;
  }
  if (!volume.init(card))           //error statement
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find FAT16/FAT32 partition.\nMake sure you've formatted the card");
    return;
  }
    if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }

}

void loop() {
  myFile = SD.open(b);
if (myFile) {
      p=myFile.read();
      Serial.write(p);
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();

}
```

Comment: error: Sd2Card card does not name a type / SdVolume volume does not name a type

Comment: Can you share the connection of sd card module with the arduino uno so that i can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So what I have done is create a file in loop.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

int chipSelectNumber = 10;
String prefix = "test";
String extension = ".txt";
String filename;
int fileNumber=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }  
  initSDCard();
}
void loop() {
  createFileAndEnterData();  

}

//This Function will create file and Enter modbus data in the file
void createFileAndEnterData(){

 String temp;
 temp = prefix;
 temp.concat(fileNumber);
 temp.concat(extension);
 filename = temp;
 Serial.println(filename);
 fileNumber++;
 boolean statusFileCreate = createFile(filename);
 if(statusFileCreate){
  Serial.println("File Creation Successful");
 }
 else{
  Serial.println("File Creation Unsuccessful");
 }
 delay(1000);
}

boolean createFile(String fileName){
  myFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  if(myFile){
    Serial.print("Creating file : ");
    Serial.print(fileName);
    Serial.print(" ");
    myFile.println("");
    myFile.close();
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}


void initSDCard(){

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(chipSelectNumber)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done."); 
}

void openFile(String fileName){ 
  myFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("Opened File");
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  } 
}
void deleteFile(String filename){

}
void writeFile(String fileName){
    // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open(fileName);
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println(fileName);

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());

    }
    myFile.close();

  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

}
```

There are some unnecessary functions, just avoid that.
The following function will create file:-

```
void createFileAndEnterData(){

 String temp;
 temp = prefix;
 temp.concat(fileNumber);
 temp.concat(extension);
 filename = temp;
 Serial.println(filename);
 fileNumber++;
 boolean statusFileCreate = createFile(filename);
 if(statusFileCreate){
  Serial.println("File Creation Successful");
 }
 else{
  Serial.println("File Creation Unsuccessful");
 }
 delay(1000);
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.
Thank You.